# Как перебрать все ячейки первого столбца dataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, datagridview

Пытаюсь перебрать все ячейки первого столбца. Как обратится к ячейке через столбец??

```
for each (DataGridViewColumn ^ row in dataGridView1->Columns){ //перебираю все столбцы
    if (row->Index == 1) {   // нахожу нужный столбец
        for each (DataGridViewCell ^ cell in ?????) { // Как правильно обратится к ячейке??
            cell->Style->BackColor = Color::Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Или может есть способ попроще?

Answer (score 0):

```
for each (DataGridViewRow^ row in dataGridView1->Rows)
{
    row->Cells[0]->Style->BackColor = Color::Black;
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Всё сработало. Я прям чувствовал, что велосипед строю)))

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]